# need code for sliding menu bar

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am looking for some code in JQuery for a sliding menu bar just like the one on [this](http://rebekahmoses.co/home.html)
page. If anyone can help. The menu bar at this site was done with css3 and html5. Trying to avoid if possible.

Comment: Please note, StackOverflow is for getting help with problems in code that you have written.

Comment: I have written the code on that site, but looking for a better way. can't find anything and was looking for advice as if it is possible. I am a newby and was after some help.....

Comment: have just fixed the link. @Rory, I appreciate your comments, but if you are not going to help, please don't comment.

Comment: how else should you know, we are a helping community, not a code-for-other-community? Try it on your own and pls come back, when you find any problems or get stuck or kinda that, then we will help you.

Comment: As a newby I was hoping the community would point me in the right direction as I am having troubles...The way you state your comments does not help broaden or represent a community. I have tried and only been able to do it in css3, as I have stated previiously.....

Comment: Out of curiosity why do you want to avoid CSS3 and HTML5?

Comment: Hi Todd, welcome to StackOverflow! We love helping people figure out problems they are having with their code, but we do not just provide full solutions for problems. Make an attempt at solving the problem, and when you hit a roadblock feel free to post here for help. We are a community, but we have rules. Please [review our FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) on what you can ask and how, and you're experience will be a lot more beneficial. Thanks!

Comment: @Billy I am avoiding these as I am having problems with certain browsers that don't support these properly. As I am only learning JQuery, I would much prefer to use this instead.

Comment: @Todd - You probably just want to place your menu off page and make it slide onto the page using jQuery's animate() function.

Comment: That sounds better than trying to use JS onload,as the menu still shows on the page. Where might I find some info on placing off page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a raw jQuery menu, you could use animate(). See this JSFiddle for an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/turiyag/7tcbc/3/

```
$("#menu").animate({"width":"80%"},10000);
```

Comment: Thank You This was the start I was looking for, now I know where to start I can have a go at it myself and have a great reference point.